# how to fix "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" exception in xampp virtual host

Tags: laravel, xampp, virtualhost

hosting a site on VPS using xampp virtual host... and it's enabaled for public access through firewall...site is working properly...but some time it cannot working...display bellow error.

```
"This site can’t be reached www.xxx.com took too long to respond.
```

Search Google for xxx
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

why this happend?  this is my virtual host code

```
ServerName xxx.com
ServerAlias www.xxx.com

DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.com\public"
ErrorLog "logs/xxx.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/xxx.com-access.log" common
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.com">
    Require all granted
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Comment: **VPS using xampp**, what trickery is this?

Comment: why is that? it's not a way?

Comment: I think you do not understand what VPS means; it is Virtual Private Server; which you usually buy (as a service) from a provider like https://digitalocean.com etc... Obviously you can set "VPS" yourself but then its not really VPS its just a server that you control. So my first comment was a irony-like joke. Anyway I can not really help you with your issue. Good luck!